# My grade calculator with special weighting

Tags: javascript, css, html5

My school has a special `65%` formal `35%` informal weighting, so I made something to find what your grade would be if you added or changed a grade.
`http://retep-mathwizard.github.io/gradecalc/gradecalc.html`

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Grade Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gradecalc.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gradecalc.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
    <input id="ing" placeholder="Informal grades, seperate by commas."><br>
    <input id="fog" placeholder="Formal grades, seperate by commas."><br>
    <input type="radio" name='type' onclick="changeoldgradedisplay()" id='radio_new_grade' >New<br>
    <input type="radio" name='type' onclick="changeoldgradedisplay()" id='radio_old_grade' checked>Change<br>
    <input id="old_grade_input" display='none' placeholder="old grade">
    <input id="new_grade_input" placeholder="new grade"><br>
    <input type="radio" name='gradetype' id='informal_radio'>Informal<br>
    <input type="radio" name='gradetype' id='formal_radio' checked>Formal<br>
    <button onclick="add_grades()" > Go </button>
    <p id='previous_grade'></p>
    <p id='new_grade'></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS:

```
#fog, #ing {

  width: 300px;
}
```

#### JS:

```
function changeoldgradedisplay() {
    if (document.getElementById('radio_old_grade').checked) {
        document.getElementById('old_grade_input').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('old_grade_input').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function get_average(items) {
    var sum = 0;
    var len = items.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(items[i]);
    }
    return sum/len;
}

function add_grades() {
    var formal_grades = document.getElementById('fog').value.split(',');
    var informal_grades = document.getElementById('ing').value.split(',');
    var previous_grade = (get_average(formal_grades) * .65) + (get_average(informal_grades) * .35);

    document.getElementById('previous_grade').innerHTML = 'Estimate of previous grade - ' + previous_grade.toFixed(2);

    var is_formal = document.getElementById('formal_radio').checked;
    var gradelist = null;

    if (is_formal) {
        new_grade = document.getElementById("new_grade_input").value;
        if (document.getElementById('radio_old_grade').checked) {
            old_grade = document.getElementById("old_grade_input").value;
            formal_grades[formal_grades.indexOf(old_grade)] = new_grade
        } else {
            formal_grades.push(new_grade);
        }
    } else {
        new_grade = document.getElementById("new_grade_input").value;
        if (document.getElementById('radio_old_grade').checked) {
            old_grade = document.getElementById("old_grade_input").value;
            informal_grades[informal_grades.indexOf(old_grade)] = new_grade
        } else {
            informal_grades.push(new_grade);
        }
    }

    var new_grade = (get_average(formal_grades) * .65) + (get_average(informal_grades) * .35);
    document.getElementById('new_grade').innerHTML = 'Estimate of new grade - ' + new_grade.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of minor things:

- `fog` and `ing` aren't very meaningful id names, they would be better as something like `formal_grades` and `informal_grades` instead.
- This part of the code:

```js
var is_formal = document.getElementById('formal_radio').checked;    
var gradelist = null;

if (is_formal) {
    new_grade = document.getElementById("new_grade_input").value;
    if (document.getElementById('radio_old_grade').checked) {
        old_grade = document.getElementById("old_grade_input").value;
        formal_grades[formal_grades.indexOf(old_grade)] = new_grade
    } else {
        formal_grades.push(new_grade);
    }
} else {
    new_grade = document.getElementById("new_grade_input").value;
    if (document.getElementById('radio_old_grade').checked) {
        old_grade = document.getElementById("old_grade_input").value;
        informal_grades[informal_grades.indexOf(old_grade)] = new_grade
    } else {
        informal_grades.push(new_grade);
    }
}
```

repeats very similar code where the only difference is which array is used. Also, `gradelist` isn't used anywhere. You can avoid the repetition like this:

```js
var is_formal = document.getElementById('formal_radio').checked;
var gradelist = is_formal ? formal_grades : informal_grades;

new_grade = document.getElementById("new_grade_input").value;
if (document.getElementById('radio_old_grade').checked) {
    old_grade = document.getElementById("old_grade_input").value;
    gradelist[gradelist.indexOf(old_grade)] = new_grade
} else {
    gradelist.push(new_grade);
}
```

by assigning the array that needs to be used to `gradelist`.

This works because when you assign an array (or any object) to a variable in javascript, it assigns the *reference* to the array instead of copying the value. For example, if `formal_grades` is assigned to `gradelist` they will both refer to the same array.

Comment: fog stands for **fo**rmal **g**rades, ing stands for **in**formal **g**rades

Comment: Also, I thought of assigning a gradelist, but later I recalculate using both lists, and I couldn't differentiate between the 2. (`var new_grade = (get_average(formal_grades) * .65) + (get_average(informal_grades) * .35);`)

Comment: Sorry I must have missed that! I'll modify my answer.
I understood why they were called fog and ing, but I would still recommend not shortening them just for clarity.

Comment: I've added an explanation about how assigning to gradelist would work, let me know if I haven't explained it well enough